# Creating UIButton programmatically with custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to create 3-4 buttons programmatically but with a custom class and a specific value/key pair, but I struggle on how to do this exactly.
The button I want to create must have a custom class named "AnswerButton". Adding a UIButton.tag shouldnt be a problem, so I can exactly tell what button has been clicked, right?

Here is the code I use to create buttons:

```c
NSMutableArray *catNames;
catNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
[catNames addObject:@"Boote"];
[catNames addObject:@"Gewässer"];
[catNames addObject:@"Technik"];
[catNames addObject:@"Krims Krams"];

[self dynamiclyCreateButtons:4 :catNames];

- (void)dynamiclyCreateButtons:(int)howMany :(NSMutableArray*)catNames {
    float standard_btnHeight = 30.0;
    float standard_btnWidth = 200.0;
    CGFloat p = 120;

    for(int i = 0; i != howMany; i++){
        UIButton *catBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [catBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, standard_btnWidth, standard_btnHeight)];
        [catBtn setCenter:CGPointMake(100.0f, p)];
        [catBtn setTitle:[catNames objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [catBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:catBtn];
        p=p+40;
        catBtn = nil;
    }
}
```

//Edit
What I mean by custom class:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r2oz.png

**//Edit 2 (The correct answer, since I cannot post an answer myself to point it out better)**

Just here to point it out and find the answer easier: Answer by Greg is correct.
You shouldn't create the buttons with the default class but with your custom class instead:

Replace

```
UIButton *catBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

with

```
AnswerButton *catBtn = [AnswerButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Dont forget to import the class!

Comment: What do you mean by custom class? Do you want to create all of your button with class "AnswerButton" or do you want to create every button with different class?

Comment: Are you looking for a class named AnswerButton derived from UIButton?

Comment: @Greg I want all the created UIButtons to have the custom class "AnswerButton". See the screenshot in the first post.

Comment: @HRM No, AnswerButton is my own class I have in the project. I want the buttons to have this custom class so I can use the "User Defined Runtime Attributes"

Comment: Replace your UIButton *catBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; with AnswerButton *catBtn = [AnswerButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

Comment: @AashishJoshi It works without it, but I'm pretty sure I had a good reason. Cant remember it tho. :(

Comment: @Greg It had to be this easy, damn it.. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This...

```
-(void)dynamiclyCreateButtons:(int)howMany :(NSMutableArray*)catNames {
    float standard_btnHeight = 30.0;
    float standard_btnWidth = 200.0;
    CGFloat p = 120;


    for(int i = 0; i != howMany; i++){
        UIButton *catBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [catBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, standard_btnWidth, standard_btnHeight)];
        [catBtn setCenter:CGPointMake(100.0f, p)];
        [catBtn setTag:i];
        [catBtn setTitle:[catNames objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [catBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:catBtn];
        p=p+40;
        catBtn = nil;
    }
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button.Tag = %d",[sender tag]);
}
```

EDIT: If you want to use the custom class, you have to create a class inherited from `UIButton`. Then import this class in your view controller.

After that replace `UIButton` with `YourCustomButton` like..

```
YourCustomButton *catBtn = [YourCustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Comment: Thanks, the TAG thing is now working. Any idea on how to add the class to that button?

Comment: your welcome. I cant understand you you want to say by "add the class".

Comment: Greg pointed me to the right direction. See my second edit in the main post. Sorry if it wasnt clear enough in the first place.

Comment: See my edit. It may help you. In your firs post it was not too much clear